# Regex: the "replace" pattern

Tags: c#, regex, str-replace

I have a string which I want to manipulate. Problem is that the replacement contains also regular expressions.

```
var result = Regex.Replace("Abc", "\r\nAbc\r\n", "\r\n"); 
// or something like that, it can be also \t and so on...
```

But the result is not a newline, but the string "\r\n".

PS: By the way, if I want to replace something by nothing, as very simple example:

```
Regex.Replace("abc", "abc", "")
```

regex seems to fail. Cannot strings are replaced by an empty string?

Comment: \r\n is a new line (return + newline) which is used on some operating systems.

Comment: If you want to replace a string by an empty string just use `String.Replace()`: `string result = "abc".Replace("abc", "");`

Comment: Please see my answer @Crud stated below

Answer (score 0):

You can just use as follows instaed of using regex.

```
string result = "abc".Replace("abc", string.empty);
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but the input text is very very long, and I have very manifold issues. So that I can´t list each complex issue here. They are only very simple falls here, just as an example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace("Abc", "\r\nAbc\r\n", System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: There is no an OS-specific problem, I think. I know no additional options, which I could specify the replacement-string, as a regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the string literal `@` identifier before your regex.

```
var result = Regex.Replace("Abc", @"\r\nAbc\r\n", "\r\n");
```

My guess it that they are being read in as escape characters before they get to the regex engine.

Basically, the pattern getting passed in is this:

```
"
Abc
"
```

Intead of this:

```
"\r\nAbc\r\n"
```